# hypothesis testing with linear models and gams

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, generalized-additive-model

I hope this question doesn't get doomed as being too simple or confusing. I'm just a little confused and would like to understand it better.

So my question is the following. By what I know I normally can compare the fit between two linear models using a anova. For example, I can test a linear model with against the null-hypothesis, that all predictors have a slope of 0, by doing the following:

```
library(mgcv)
data("marketing", package = "datarium")
lm0 = lm(sales ~ 1, data = marketing)
lm1 = lm(sales ~ youtube + facebook, data=marketing); summary(lm0)
anova(lm0, lm1, test="F")
```

The anova output then is the following:

```
Model 1: sales ~ 1
Model 2: sales ~ youtube + facebook
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1    199 7800.7                                  
2    197  802.0  2    6998.7 859.62 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Based on the very small p-value I would conclude that there is evidence, that at least one predictor has a slope that is not 0. However, when I'm doing the following:

```
# compare the fit of a linear model and a gam
# What is my null hypothesis?
gam0 = gam(sales ~ youtube + facebook, data=marketing)
gam1 = gam(sales ~ s(youtube) + s(facebook), data=marketing)
anova(gam0, gam1, test = "F")
```

The output of the anova is:

```
Model 1: sales ~ youtube + facebook
Model 2: sales ~ s(youtube) + s(facebook)
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev     Df Deviance      F    Pr(>F)    
1    197.00     801.96                                     
2    190.47     550.55 6.5315   251.41 13.398 2.167e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And I'm not really sure what conclusions to draw from it. I don't even know what my null hypothesis is exactly. I think that due to the `gam1` having smoothing terms, that the p-value is just an estimate. Could I for example conclude that I have evidence the model `gam1` fits the data in general better, without looking at certain predictors? I'd be really thankful for any help:)

Answer (score 2):

You give no details about what the variables `youtube` and `facebook` look like, but I will assume they are measured as continuous variables. Your model `gam0` is a conventional linear fit on both variables: you see that the  residual deviance of `gam1` is quite close to that of `lm1`. Your model `gam1`, on the other hand, makes `sales` dependent not on a linear function of the predictors, but on respective smooth functions of the predictors. It is fair to say that `gam0` is nested on `gam1`, since a linear function of e.g. `youtube` is a particular case of `s(youtube)`.

What you are seeing is a substantial drop in deviance in going from `gam0` to `gam1`, much larger than would be expected on account only of the larger number of (equivalent) degrees of freeedom consumed in `gam1`. So, to answer your question, yes, you might interpret the results as evidence of non-linear influence of either or both predictors over and above what a linear fit is able to capture.

Comment: thank you very much, that helped a lot! And yes, the variables are all continous to my knowledge. I fitted the gam0 as a linear model within the `gam` function as I tought I need to fit both models in an anova with the same function.

Comment: You are welcome.